# Instagram Scraper running to slow

Tags: python, performance, multithreading, web-scraping

Can someone help me how to speed up this scraping process getting all the usernames from the # 'cats' on instagram. My goal is to make this as fast as possible because currently the process is kinda slow. Maybe using multithreading?

```
from instaloader import Instaloader

HASHTAG = 'cats'

loader = Instaloader(sleep=False)

users = []
for post in loader.get_hashtag_posts(HASHTAG):
    if post.owner_username not in users:
        users.append(post.owner_username) 
    print(post.owner_username)
```

---

The following is a profiling run, ordered by: cumulative time.

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    331/1    0.002    0.000   18.736   18.736 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.001    0.001   18.736   18.736 GetUsernamesFromHashtags.py:1(<module>)
       36    0.001    0.000   18.468    0.513 instaloadercontext.py:354(get_json)
       36    0.000    0.000   18.453    0.513 sessions.py:528(get)
       36    0.001    0.000   18.452    0.513 sessions.py:457(request)
       36    0.001    0.000   18.368    0.510 sessions.py:608(send)
       36    0.001    0.000   18.126    0.504 adapters.py:394(send)
       36    0.001    0.000   18.009    0.500 connectionpool.py:446(urlopen)
      492    0.001    0.000   18.002    0.037 socket.py:575(readinto)
      492    0.001    0.000   18.000    0.037 pyopenssl.py:295(recv_into)
      492    0.002    0.000   17.999    0.037 SSL.py:1795(recv_into)
      492   17.994    0.037   17.994    0.037 {built-in method _openssl.SSL_read}
       36    0.001    0.000   17.993    0.500 connectionpool.py:319(_make_request)
       36    0.000    0.000   17.912    0.498 client.py:1292(getresponse)
       36    0.001    0.000   17.911    0.498 client.py:299(begin)
     2521    0.002    0.000   17.872    0.007 {method 'readline' of '_io.BufferedReader' objects}
       36    0.001    0.000   17.860    0.496 client.py:266(_read_status)
       35    0.000    0.000   17.134    0.490 structures.py:180(owner_username)
       35    0.000    0.000   17.134    0.490 structures.py:165(owner_profile)
       35    0.000    0.000   17.133    0.490 structures.py:141(_full_metadata)
       35    0.001    0.000   17.133    0.490 structures.py:132(_obtain_metadata)
       36    0.000    0.000    1.336    0.037 instaloader.py:835(get_hashtag_posts)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably won't be able to do much to speed up `get_hashtag_posts` since that's an API call; if you try to hammer it by running multiple queries in parallel, a well-designed API will interpret that as a DDOS attack and rate-limit you.

As far as your code goes, though, you should be using a set instead of a list, since sets are optimized for the exact thing you're doing:

```
from typing import Set


users: Set[str] = set()
for post in loader.get_hashtag_posts(HASHTAG):
    users.add(post.owner_username)
```

This should be a constant-time operation, whereas a list will take longer to search the longer it is (linear-time).

Comment: NameError: name 'Set' is not defined. how can I fix that? (sry I'm new to python)

Comment: `from typing import Set` (at the top of the file)